# Move Plastic SCM repository to another space

Tags: synchronization, replication, plasticscm

How export/import repositories to another PC thare is offline. I try "cm replicate br:/... --package=box.pk". But I need copy complete repositories with all branches to one file.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This command allows to create a replication package only for a selected branch

```
cm replicate src_br_spec --package=pack_file [AuthOptions]
    (Package based replication. Creates a replication package in the source 
    server with the selected branch
```

If you want to migrate your repos and the second server is still offline, let's follow a different approach:

- You can directly move the databases from one location to the other (if you are using the same database backend in both locations).
- Other option could be to export the repos with the `cm fast-export` command and then when new server is available, import the repos running the cm `fast-import` command. It will generate an export file per repository.